# How do I find the Delta A, B, C and L from the LAB colorspace?

Tags: lab-color-space

I'm building the color Spectrograph which will show the target color and other lab dip colors on the graph. All the colors on Spectrograph will be showing based on Delta A (as Xaxis) and Delta B (as Yaxis).

The only problem is that how do I find the Delta A and Delta B values from the LAB color-space from target and desired one?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. This link has very well written documentation for finding the Delta E, Delta 76, Delta 94 and Delta CMC. http://zschuessler.github.io/DeltaE/learn/

In addition to this, the Delta A, B, C and L can be found from this whole equation as well.

[image]

And these are the equations to get Delta A, B, C and L separately.

**Delta A Formula:** 
 
`Delta A = Target Color A Value - Lab Dip Color A Value` 
[image]

**Delta B Formula:** 
 
`Delta B = Target Color-space B Value - Lab Dip Color-space B Value` 
[image]

**Delta L Formula:** 
 
`Delta L = Target Color-space L Value - Lab Dip Color-space L Value` 
[image]

**Delta C Formula:** 
 
`C1 = Target Color-space A Value + Lab Dip Color-space A Value` 
`C2 = Target Color-space B Value + Lab Dip Color-space B Value` 
`Delta C = C1 - C2` 
[image]